# iOS avplayer not playing remote video

Tags: ios, avplayer

I want to play a remote .mp4 video in AvPlayer. Here is my code

```
 NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:encodedString];
 self.asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
 self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoUrl];
 self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

 self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
 self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

[self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.player currentItem]];



self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.myPlayerView.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];



self.videoPlaybackPosition = 0;

[self.player play];



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

   if (object == self.player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed --> %ld",(long)self.player.currentItem.status);

    } else if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");

        [self.player play];


    } else if (self.player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

    }
  }
}
```

AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay is taking some time to buffering the video and it only  working for one time.
But the same code I use to record a video and play it from temp file. In that case it works fine. After uploading the video to server, when I try to play it from server, the video plays for just  1-2 seconds. After that the video got stuck, and nothing happens. I can't understand where is my problem.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: ya... i completed it..

Comment: can you add solution here.